Minimize idle CPU usage of async thread in Tokio / Rust
The following code:
use tokio::runtime;
use std::{time, thread};

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
    let rt = runtime::Runtime::new().unwrap();

    let future = rt.spawn(async move{
        let mut limit = 200;
        loop {
            limit -= 1;
            if limit == 0 {
                break;
            }
            tokio::time::sleep(tokio::time::Duration::from_millis(100)).await;
        }
    });
    rt.block_on(future).unwrap();
}

measured with
perf stat -e cycles 

gives 0.11 seconds User and 0.03 seconds Sys time (20.28 secs elapsed, so I sum user and sys time to get 0.7% CPU ). Can I do any better with Tokio?
(Latest stable Rust from Rustup, Debian Stable VM)

You're effectively blocking the main thread every 100ms so I'm not surprised it's burning some CPU.

nothing in your code does anything besides wait and print, so just remove all the other stuff https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6cd68c2e219320d7ea9d4f0a36409a8b

I know what the code is doing :) I’m building an interactive TUI app (Ratatui), so I want to know how much it will consume in idle.

Are you running your program built with the --release profile? My stats running this are 0.006s user and 0.007s sys.
